# JSON data undefined from external file in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm developing a d3.js app that reads data from a external JSON file. I feel like I've tried everything, but everytime I try to load the data and display it in console.log, console.log displays the data as `undefined`. I'm running a Python web server with `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` on Firefox to avoid cross origin resource sharing problems, but I haven't had any luck actually getting the data into the browser. My code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <title>JSON Data Read</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>        
        <script>
var dataset;
d3.json('course.json', function(error, json) {
    dataset = json;
    console.log(dataset);
});
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any advice?

Edit: JSON file

```
{
    "course_id": "Course 1", 
    "prereqs": null, 
    "off_w": null, 
    "name": "Course 1 Title"
}{
    "course_id": "Course 2", 
    "prereqs": null, 
    "off_w": null, 
    "name": "Course 2 Title"
}{
    "course_id": "Course 3", 
    "prereqs": null, 
    "off_w": null, 
    "name": "Course 3 Title"
}
```

Comment: Look at the request in the webinspector tab (F12 > Network).

Comment: @Halcyon It loads the `course.json` file with a 200

Comment: @Halcyon `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 6 column 2 of the JSON data` I've looked at the JSON file and can't figure out where the whitespace character is on line 6. I generated the JSON using Python, so the problem must be there I guess?

Comment: Can post the JSON file? (or a part containing everyting up to that line)

Comment: @Halcyon posted. Any thoughts?

Comment: Yep, thats not valid JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSON file is not valid JSON:

```
{
    "course_id": "Course 1", 
    "prereqs": null, 
    "off_w": null, 
    "name": "Course 1 Title"
}/* <-- JSON block ends here, no further content is expected */{
    "course_id": "Course 2", 
    "prereqs": null, 
    "off_w": null, 
    "name": "Course 2 Title"
}{
    "course_id": "Course 3", 
    "prereqs": null, 
    "off_w": null, 
    "name": "Course 3 Title"
}
```

This would be valid:

```
[ {
    "course_id": "Course 1", 
    "prereqs": null, 
    "off_w": null, 
    "name": "Course 1 Title"
}, {
    "course_id": "Course 2", 
    "prereqs": null, 
    "off_w": null, 
    "name": "Course 2 Title"
}, {
    "course_id": "Course 3", 
    "prereqs": null, 
    "off_w": null, 
    "name": "Course 3 Title"
} ]
```

Added `[`, `]` and a `,` between the objects.

---

The error message is a little bit cryptic. JSON is whitespace **in**sensitive so after `}` you can have as much whitespace as you want, just not another `{` or any other non-whitespace character.